# DMA/Microblaze Reads Incorrect Data after Direct Access to Physical Addresses of Userspace Pages (Kernel Scatter/Gather)

Tags: caching, kernel, fpga, dma, pci

What I am trying to accomplish is make a block of memory in userspace directly accessible by a DMA core in a FPGA board over PCIe (without any interference by the kernel).

In order to do so, I use **posix_memalign()** in userspace to allocate a block of memory (4M) in userspace and then pass its virtual address to the kernel via a write operation.

In kernel I use the code below to get all pages of the userspace memory block in order to create a Scatter/Gather list and obtain all physical addresses for each page:

```
static ssize_t  posix_memory_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buffer, size_t count, loff_t *off)
{

    int repeat;
    int temporary_point;

    int buffer_mapped_pages;
    int sg_table_value;

    int buffer_dma_buffers = 0;

    u32 *u32_posix_buffer = NULL;

    int buffer_entries = count / PAGE_SIZE;

    struct page **buffer_page_array;

    dma_addr_t *dma_address_list_pointer;
    int *dma_length_list_pointer;

    struct sg_table *dma_sg_table;
    struct scatterlist *scatterlist_pointer;

    if(posix_buffer != NULL)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s [DEBUG MESSAGE-POSIX MEMORY WRITE] Buffer's Virtual Address is 0x%016lX\n", driver_name, (unsigned long)posix_buffer);


        u32_posix_buffer = (u32 *)posix_buffer;


        for(repeat = 0; repeat < 16; repeat++)
        {
            printk(KERN_ALERT "%s [DEBUG MESSAGE-POSIX MEMORY WRITE] Buffer Data: %d\n", driver_name, u32_posix_buffer[repeat]);
        }

        buffer_page_array = kmalloc(sizeof(struct page *) * buffer_entries, GFP_KERNEL);

        down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);

        buffer_mapped_pages = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, (unsigned long)(posix_buffer), buffer_entries, 1, 0, buffer_page_array, NULL);


        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s [DEBUG MESSAGE-POSIX MEMORY WRITE] Buffer Mapped Pages %d\n", driver_name, buffer_mapped_pages);


        for(repeat = 0; repeat < buffer_mapped_pages; repeat++) 
        {
            if (!PageReserved(buffer_page_array[repeat]))
            {
                SetPageDirty(buffer_page_array[repeat]);
            }
            page_cache_release(buffer_page_array[repeat]);

        }

        up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);

        dma_sg_table = kmalloc(sizeof(struct sg_table), GFP_KERNEL);


        sg_table_value = sg_alloc_table(dma_sg_table, buffer_mapped_pages, GFP_KERNEL);


        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s [DEBUG MESSAGE-POSIX MEMORY WRITE] Scatter/Gather Table Return Value %d\n", driver_name, sg_table_value);

        scatterlist_pointer = dma_sg_table->sgl;    

        for(repeat = 0; repeat < buffer_mapped_pages; repeat++)
        {
            sg_set_page(scatterlist_pointer, buffer_page_array[repeat], PAGE_SIZE, 0);
            scatterlist_pointer = sg_next(scatterlist_pointer);
        }


        scatterlist_pointer = dma_sg_table->sgl;

        buffer_dma_buffers = dma_map_sg(&dev->dev, scatterlist_pointer, buffer_mapped_pages, DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL);


        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s [DEBUG MESSAGE-POSIX MEMORY WRITE] DMA Buffers are: %d\n", driver_name, buffer_dma_buffers);

        dma_address_list_pointer = (dma_addr_t *)kmalloc(sizeof(dma_addr_t) * buffer_dma_buffers, GFP_KERNEL);
        dma_length_list_pointer = (int *)kmalloc(sizeof(int) * buffer_dma_buffers, GFP_KERNEL);


        for(repeat = 0; repeat < buffer_dma_buffers; repeat++)
        {
            dma_address_list_pointer[repeat] = sg_dma_address(scatterlist_pointer);
            dma_length_list_pointer[repeat] = sg_dma_len(scatterlist_pointer);


            scatterlist_pointer = sg_next(scatterlist_pointer);

            printk(KERN_ALERT "%s [DEBUG MESSAGE-POSIX MEMORY WRITE] Buffer Page %d DMA Physical Address is: 0x%016lX [SIZE %d Bytes]\n", driver_name, repeat, (unsigned long)dma_address_list_pointer[repeat], dma_length_list_pointer[repeat]);

        }   


        scatterlist_pointer = dma_sg_table->sgl;

        //pci_dma_sync_sg_for_device(dev, scatterlist_pointer, buffer_dma_buffers, DMA_TO_DEVICE);


        for(repeat = 0; repeat < buffer_mapped_pages; repeat++) 
        {
            writel(dma_address_list_pointer[repeat], (u32 *)bar1_address_virtual + repeat);
        }

        temporary_point = repeat;

        for(repeat = 0; repeat < buffer_mapped_pages; repeat++) 
        {
            writel(dma_length_list_pointer[repeat], (u32 *)bar1_address_virtual + repeat + temporary_point);
        }       

        write_remote_register(bar0_address_virtual, BAR0_OFFSET_GPIO_NOTIFIER + ZERO_OFFSET, (u32) (OPERATION_SET_DMA_ADDRESS_LENGTH_ARRAY_SIZE | buffer_dma_buffers));

}
```

With 4M userspace memory block it seems that I get correctly all the physical addresses for each of the 1024 pages (page size is 4096 bytes).

Then I write those addresses to a BRAM memory in my FPGA.

Both the DMA core and a Microblaze Processor use those addresses to read over PCIe the data that are already written by the userspace application that allocates the previous memory block.

For some reason, though, the read operations by the DMA/Microblaze are not correct.

The data that are stored in the userspace memory block are contiguous increasing values (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16..., 234, 235 etc).

Every time I read from the physical address of a page it seems that I get a piece of such contiguous values that makes me believe that I get correct data.

The problem is that I get the exact same piece of contiguous increasing values for all pages that I access.

What could be wrong in my case? Could this be a cache coherency issue?

Comment: Have you tried allocating the memory in the kernel instead using dma_alloc_coherent()? If you can, it might make things simpler.

Comment: For starters you'll need to pin the pages so they aren't moved or swapped out by the kernel.  What architecture are you running on?

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a driver, called portalmem, that enables user-space to share memory with FPGAs over PCIe and AXI. (https://github.com/cambridgehackers/connectal/blob/master/drivers/portalmem/portalmem.c)

The portalmem driver allocates memory in the kernel and provides a dma_buf file descriptor so that the application can mmap() it.

The pcie and zynq drivers use the dma_buf file descriptor to access the scatter gather list in order to pass the dma addresses to the FPGA.

One thing I noticed is the use of sg_dma_len rather than sg->length. If I remember correctly, sg_dma_len was 0 on at least one of our configurations, but sg->length had the correct value. Our driver uses sg->length and not sg_dma_len().

Because portalmem knows nothing about hardware, you can use it in combination with your FPGA driver.

Another thing that is very helpful in debugging this is to trace the PCIe requests going out and responses coming back, so you can see exactly which physical addresses you are reading or writing. You can use the integrated logic analyzer for this. I include a buffer that captures the 2K most recent PCIe TLPs (transaction level packets with cycle-level timestamps). This has been really helpful for debugging both functionality and performance.